# Lottery game - Not allowed to input the same number twice - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am very new to javaScript and I am currently trying to code a Lottery Game. The User is allowed to input 6 numbers between 1 and 49 and then Generate 6 random numbers and it will then tell you how many Numbers you got correct.
Everything seems to be working great so far but i can not figure out how to Code that you

1. Can not input the same number twice (This should result in an error code)
2. The Randomizer isnt allowed to draw the same number twice

My Code looks like this so far:

```js
function validateBall(num) {
  let ballValue = document.getElementById("ball" + num).value;
  if (ballValue == "") {
    alert("Ball " + num + " braucht eine Zahl");
    return false;
  }


  if (isNaN(ballValue)) {
    alert("Ball " + num + " ist keine Zahl");
    return false;
  }


  let numberValue = parseInt(ballValue);
  if (numberValue <= 0 || numberValue > 49) {
    alert("Die Zahl des Balls muss zwischen 1-49 liegen");
    return false;
  }

  return numberValue;
}

function containsDuplicates(ballValue) {
  return array.length !== new Set(ballValue).size;
}


function output(str) {
  let output = document.getElementById("output");
  var tag = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode(str);
  tag.appendChild(text);

  output.appendChild(tag);
}

function Jetzt_Spielen() {
  let value1 = validateBall("1");
  if (value1 == false)
    return;

  let value2 = validateBall("2");
  if (value2 == false)
    return;

  let value3 = validateBall("3");
  if (value3 == false)
    return;

  let value4 = validateBall("4");
  if (value4 == false)
    return;

  let value5 = validateBall("5");
  if (value5 == false)
    return;

  let value6 = validateBall("6");
  if (value6 == false)
    return;

  let values = [value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6];

  let outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  outputDiv.innerHTML = "";

  let matched = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let randomNumber = Math.round(1 + Math.random() * 48);
    output("Gezogene Zahl: " + randomNumber);
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      let myBallValue = values[j];
      if (randomNumber == myBallValue) {
        matched++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  output("Du hast " + matched + " richtige Zahl(en)")
}
```

```html
<div class="gelbe_box">
  <h1>Lotto 6aus49</h1>
</div> <br>

<div class="position_middle">
  <input id="ball1" class="LottoZahlen" />
  <input id="ball2" class="LottoZahlen" />
  <input id="ball3" class="LottoZahlen" />
  <input id="ball4" class="LottoZahlen" />
  <input id="ball5" class="LottoZahlen" />
  <input id="ball6" class="LottoZahlen" />

  <button id="submitBtn" value="button" onclick=" Jetzt_Spielen();">Jetzt Spielen</button>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
```

I dont really know how to continue with this. I either did something wrong already that I cant do it with this code or I just can not figure the code(s) out..

I'd really appreciate some help!!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: To prevent the input of the same number twice, you capture and remember the previous input and then return false if the next inputed number is the same value. Same for generating codes. You just keep track of the numbers you generated and check any new number with that list. If it matches, regenerate. Finally avoid putting javascript in a `<script>` tag. Put it in its own `.js` file. This will be very helpful for your issue: `Array.prototype.includes()`

Comment: The easiest way to ensure that "Can not input the same number twice" is by putting the numbers into a _Set_. Here is some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0):

### Good UX and Restrictions

Plan the layout (HTML and essential CSS) first. To control how interaction with the user is done relies heavily on HTML and CSS, JavaScript is used to facilitate this interaction, gather user data, and process user's data and/or new data. In order to answer your question, I'm compelled to show you an approach to meet your objective and provide a solution that's foolproof for your particular problem.

**HTML**

If you require interaction from a user use a `<form>` and keep all of your relevant layout inside of it. Present only what the user needs to use, ideally a single form control like a button. Hide the rest of the HTML and restrict the user to go through phases. Instruct the user with simple messages and visual prompts. Don't use `prompt()` (it's aesthetically unappealing and popups feel "rude" IMO):

**Figure I - The Layout**

```html
<form id='lottery'><!-- Wrap <form> around everything -->
  <fieldset id='box'>
    <!-- Always have simple clear directions -->
    <legend>Click the button to begin</legend>
    <!-- Offer the user only one or two choices at a time -->
    <!-- ATM there are two empty <select> and a <button> that automatically 
         has focus (see Figure II). There's a <legend> prompting user to click
         the <button>. There's also a hidden <button> and <output> ready for
         the next phase.
    -->
    <select id='choices' multiple></select>
    <!-- This button has focus as soon as the page is loaded because it's 
         assigned "tab-index='0'" and there's a line of JavaScript
         (see Figure II)
    -->
    <button id='begin' tab-index='0'>Begin</button>
    <button id='done' tab-index="0" type='button'>Done</button>
    <select id='picked' multiple></select>
  </fieldset>
  <output id='note' class='hide'>
    <small><sup>✳️</sup>To deselect a number, click the number in field on the right</small>
  </output>
  <!-- This hidden section is the final phase which displays the user's 
       numbers, the winning lottery numbers, and the numbers that matched.
  -->
  <fieldset id='results' class='hide'>  
    <label for='final'>Your Numbers: </label><output id='final' class='array'></output><br>
    <label for='targets'>Winning Numbers: </label><output id='targets' class='array'></output><br>
    <label for='hits'>Matching Numbers: </label><output id='hits' class='array'></output><br>
    <button type='reset'>Replay</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
   // This will hold the numbers the user picks
   let numbers = [];
   /*
   This is an array of 49 empties "". It will be used as a counter and
   then later repurposed to hold the winning numbers
   */
   let A49 = [...Array(49)];
   /* 
   Throughout this example the terse syntax of the HTMLFormsElement 
   interface will be used extensively. This references the <form>
   */
   const lot = document.forms.lottery;
   
   // 1st phase init(e) populates a <select> with 49 <option>s
   lot.addEventListener('submit', init);
   /* 
   2nd phase pick(e) allows the user to pick 6 numbers, no need to validate
   user input there are 49 numbers and each number can only be picked once.
   */
   lot.addEventListener('input', pick);
   /*
   Last phase draw(e) collects the users array of 6 numbers, then generates
   a randomized array of 6 numbers, then displays both arrays with matches
   highlighted.
   */
   lot.elements.done.addEventListener('click', draw);
   lot.onreset = function() {
     window.location.reload();
   };
   lot.elements.begin.focus();

   function init(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const IO = this.elements;
     A49 = A49.map((_, index) => {
       IO.choices.insertAdjacentHTML(
         'beforeend',
         `<option value="${index + 1}">${index + 1}</option>`
       );
       return index + 1;
     });
     //...
```

This answer is huge, apologies, I'll return later on to finish explaining the rest of this code. It's foolproof and meets if not exceeds all objectives of the OP, I hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <style>
      html {
        font: 300 5vmin/1.25 'Segoe UI';
      }
      fieldset {
        max-width: 15rem;
      }
      #box {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      input,
      button,
      output,
      select,
      label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 4px;
        font: inherit;
      }
      button {
        padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        outline: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      label {
        width: 4rem;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
      mark {
        padding: 1px;
        background-color: #0047AB;
        color: gold;
      }
      small {
        font-size: 0.5rem;
      }
      legend b {
        font-family: Consolas;
      }
      select {
        width: 3rem;
        height: 9rem;
        border: 0.5 inset lightgrey;
        border-radius: 2px;
        outline: 0;
        font-family: Consolas;
      }
      #choices {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        scrollbar-width: thin;
      }
      #choices::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0.25rem;
        height: 9rem;
      }
      #picked {
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      .array {
        width: 7.5rem;
        font-family: Consolas;
      }
      .hide {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      #done {
        display: none;
      }
      #note {
        margin-top: -4px;
      }
      [type='reset'] {
        float: right;
      }
      select:focus,
      button:focus {
        color: #0047AB;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2pt cornflowerblue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="lottery">
      <fieldset id="box">
        <legend>
          Click the button to begin
        </legend>
        <select id="choices" multiple></select>
        <button id="begin" tab-index="0">Begin</button>
        <button id="done" tab-index="0" type="button">Done</button>
        <select id="picked" multiple></select>
      </fieldset>
      <output id="note" class="hide">
        <small>
          <sup>✳️</sup>To deselect a number, click the number in field on the
          right
          </small>
      </output>
      <fieldset id="results" class="hide">
        <label for="final">Your Numbers: </label>
        <output id="final" class="array"></output><br />
        <label for="targets">Winning Numbers: </label>
        <output id="targets" class="array"></output><br />
        <label for="hits">Matching Numbers: </label>
        <output id="hits" class="array"></output><br />
        <button id='replay' tab-index='0' type="reset">Replay</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
      let numbers = [];
      let A49 = [...Array(49)];

      const lot = document.forms.lottery;

      lot.addEventListener('submit', init);

      lot.addEventListener('input', pick);

      lot.elements.done.addEventListener('click', draw);

      lot.onreset = function() {
        window.location.reload();
      };

      lot.elements.begin.focus();

      function init(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const IO = this.elements;
        A49 = A49.map((_, index) => {
          IO.choices.insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            `<option value="${index + 1}">${index + 1}</option>`
          );
          return index + 1;
        });
        IO.box.firstElementChild.innerHTML = `Pick <b>6</b> numbers -- 1 to 49<sup><small>✳️</small></sup>`;
        IO.note.classList.remove('hide');
        IO.begin.remove();
        IO.done.style.display = 'inline-block';
        IO.done.disabled = true;
        IO.choices.focus();
      }

      function pick(e) {
        const IO = this.elements;
        const sel = e.target;
        if (sel.id === 'choices') {
          const copy = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].cloneNode(true);
          IO.picked.append(copy);
          numbers.push(+sel.value);
          sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].remove();
        }
        if (sel.id === 'picked') {
          const copy = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].cloneNode(true);
          IO.choices.append(copy);
          let nodeList = [...IO.choices.options];
          let ordered = nodeList.sort((a, b) => +a.value - +b.value);
          IO.choices.replaceChildren(...nodeList, ...ordered);
          numbers = numbers.filter((number) => number !== +sel.value);
          sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].remove();
        }

        if (numbers.length === 6) {
          IO.choices.disabled = true;
          IO.done.disabled = false;
          IO.done.focus();
        } else {
          IO.choices.disabled = false;
          IO.done.disabled = true;
        }
        IO.box.firstElementChild.innerHTML = `Pick <b>${
          6 - numbers.length
        }</b> numbers -- 1 to 49<sup><small>✳️</small></sup>`;
      }

      function draw(e) {
        const IO = this.closest('form').elements;
        IO.box.disabled = true;
        IO.note.classList.add('hide');
        IO.results.classList.remove('hide');
        let drawn = shuffle(A49);
        drawn.length = 6;
        let match = drawn.filter((number) => numbers.includes(number));
        IO.final.innerHTML = mark(numbers, match);
        IO.targets.innerHTML = mark(drawn, match);
        let outcome = match.length > 0 ? mark(match) : 'Goose Egg ';
        IO.hits.innerHTML = outcome;
        IO.replay.focus();
      }

      function shuffle(array) {
        let qty = array.length,
          temp,
          i;
        while (qty) {
          i = Math.floor(Math.random() * qty--);
          temp = array[qty];
          array[qty] = array[i];
          array[i] = temp;
        }
        return array;
      }

      function mark(arrayA, arrayB = arrayA) {
        arrayA.sort((a, b) => a - b);
        return arrayA.map((n) =>
          arrayB.includes(n) ? `<mark>${n}</mark>` : n
        );
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```